# Numerical integration of highly oscillating 1-D integrand (containing Bessel functions) in python

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration, quad, bessel-functions

I am attempting to numerically evaluate a real-valued integrand composed of several Bessel functions (of the first and second kind). The integrand is oscillating and decaying, and needs to be evaluated between 0 and +∞. So far, my attempts using the scipy.integrate subpackage (quad and fixed_quad) have been unsuccessful. The evaluated value jumps around when in reality it should be smooth. For certain sets of parameter values, I also receive warnings: *"IntegrationWarning: The integral is probably divergent, or slowly convergent."* (it is known to be convergent) or *"IntegrationWarning: The maximum number of subdivisions (50) has been achieved."*

The equation is from: http://dx.doi.org/10.1029/WR003i001p00241

It is also available here: http://www.aqtesolv.com/papadopu.htm

Thank you for any assistance you have in numerical integration of fussy functions in python...

CODE EXAMPLE

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import special as sps
import scipy.integrate as integrate

# define constants and variables (SI mks units):
r_w = 0.15
r_c = 0.16
b = 10
S_s = 1E-6
Q = 0.001
S = S_s*b
K=1E-8
T=K*b
alpha = (r_w**2)*S/r_c**2
def r_D(r):
    return r/r_w
def u(r,t):
    return r**2*S/(4*T*t)
def B(beta):
    return beta*sps.jv(0,beta) - 2*alpha*sps.jv(1,beta)
def A(beta):
    return beta*sps.yn(0,beta) - 2*alpha*sps.yn(1,beta)
def intd_f(beta,r,t): 
    TOP = (1-np.exp(-beta**2*r_D(r)**2)/(4*u(r,t)))*( sps.jv(0,beta*r_D(r))*A(beta) - sps.yn(0,beta*r_D(r))*B(beta) )
    BOT = (A(beta)**2 + B(beta)**2)*beta**2
    return TOP/BOT
def s(r,t):
    banana = (2*alpha*Q)/(np.pi**2*K*b)
    apple = integrate.quad(intd_f, 0, np.inf, args=(r,t))[0]
    #apple = integrate.fixed_quad(intd_f, 0, 1E100, args=(r,t))[0] # another option I have tried
    return banana*apple

#%% simple example usage...
r=np.arange(1,10,.1)
t=60*60*24*pd.Series([1/24,1,365,3650])
plt.figure()
for tt in t:
    print('time=',tt)
    snow=[]
    for rr in r:
        print('r=',rr)
        snow.append(s(rr,tt))
    plt.subplot(2,1,1)
    plt.plot(r,snow,label='t='+str(tt/(60*60*24))+'d')
    plt.subplot(2,1,2)
    plt.semilogy(r,np.abs(snow))    
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.legend()
```

Comment: Try breaking up the integral into pieces.  For example, you could sum the integrals over, say, [0.0, 0.1], [0.1, 1], [1, 10], and [10, inf];  experiment with the intervals to find one that works.  Also, when you get the warning about the maximum number of subdivisions, try increasing that limit by using the `limit` argument, e.g. `limit=200`.

Comment: The provided example is not minimal. I see `quad` used in `s()`, and `s()` is then plotted; no idea what's happening there. Try picking out _one_ function that you want to integrate and maybe show a plot.

Comment: @Nico, It is a very specific function I am trying to integrate (`int_f`, see the link in the comment) for a variety of values of `t` and `r`. There is only _one_ function being integrated, so I do not see why you take issue with the example. This example shows how `s` jumps around with changing `r` and `t` values due to `quad` having problems with this integrand.

Comment: I think one could simplify the example by writing something like: "Here's the function `int_f`, it looks so and so, and I want to integrate it. However, I'm getting the error such and such when running the above code." Anything more than that (like the parameters `t` and `r`) is distracting, imho.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have bad news for you: Oscillatory integrands must be dealt with by special methods, for example Filon's method. Reading through the scipy docs, I see no way to do this. However, it appears [MPMath](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/calculus/integration.html) implements precisely what you are looking for, and even gives an example using Bessel functions.

Comment: Thank you for this. I have not used that package before and will give it a go. I agree that scipy looks to be somewhat limited with respect to the implementation of various numerical methods adapted to a variety of "special" cases.